# Responsive Scheduler

Tags: web, responsive

I'm designing a simple scheduler in which I don't need any information except days/hours, no calendar information, no titles, no description, just days/hours.

The scheduler consist in a selection of 20 minutes intervals, with the option to copy, paste and delete any selected block of hours.

The main problem I'am facing, is that the scheduler need to be responsive.

For Web it was kind of simple, because I could play with a "click and drag" gesture to select the hours in any day (I poorly sketched this, for illustration purpose):

[image: WebSketch]

But for mobile, the "click and drag" gesture obviously doesn't exist as that (if you scroll over the scheduler it goes to the next hours), so I tried to imagine how the user could select the hours as easy as the web. I din't want to go to the "Google's calendar" way, because touching into an interval and then selecting the hours was so much for me, so I remembered an app (I can't remember the name) that uses a *weird* control to drag the block hour as you want, something like this (purple block):

[image: MobileSketch]

So when an interval is touched (on focus) the control appear and you can increase, decrease the interval of hours, when is out of focus the controller disappear.

But I have my doubts, I don't know if this is an easy and simple way, or if Am I just only overthinking it, so I want your general opinions, what do you think about this approach? Can you think of something simpler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's ok to have the resize controls as in the last mock-up.

Instead of copy and paste, you could actually drag and drop on a mobile device.
You tap once, the red controls appear, but if you try to drag from anywhere else but the red resize controls, the block sticks to your finger, and you can move to edges to scroll. Bonus points if you show a faded block to indicate where you're about to drop the time block, that updates as you scroll in a different region.

One thing I would pay attention to, is that when you have 1 hr time blocks, it would be more intuitive to have 8AM be top aligned inside its block, rather than in the middle as it is now, to communicate to the user where 8 AM actually starts.

If the large red dot is +, I would consider an alternative of double-tapping or other gesture, in a free slot, to quickly add a 20m time block, which you can then immediately resize to your heart's desire.

Good luck!